# How to unbox from object to type it contains, not knowing that type at compile time?

Tags: c#, unboxing

At the run-time I get boxed instance of some type. How to unbox it to underlying type?

```
Object obj;
String variable = "Some text";

obj = variable // boxing;

// explicit unboxing, because we know the type of variable at compile time.

var x = (String)obj     

// Now let's pretend that we don't know the type of underlying object at compile time. 

Type desiredType = obj.GetType(); // But we can figure out.

//And now the question. 
//How to express something like this:

var y = (desiredType)obj; //Need to get unboxed instance of initial variable here;
```

Comment: `String` is a reference type, so no boxing occur when converting to `object`

Comment: _Value type objects have two representations: an unboxed form and a boxed form. Reference types (like `string`) are always in a boxed form._

Comment: Well maybe bad example with the string. But never the less how to do it?

Comment: Side note: you need much more interesting construct to store value of not-know-at-compile-time value type than `var y = (desiredType)obj;`

Comment: That's why I'm asking. Just wanted to illustrate what I need :)

Comment: What is the purpose here? what are you trying to do, that you think you will be able to do with `y`, but which you couldn't previously do with `obj` ?

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance(currentProperty.ReflectedType);` returns object. But I need to iterate its properties via reflection for instance.

Comment: And how it relates to boxing and unboxing? GetType() will give you correct type and reflection methods take object as argument anyway...

Comment: @PaulKyrejto: You can still do that: `var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(currentProperty.ReflectedType); instance.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetValue(instance, null));` <- This is an example that would give you the values of all properties of the new instance.

Comment: Side note: Paul, I'd recommend to keep your question as is (and consider to accept Marc's answer) and than ask separate question if you need to. I believe you actually used your own meaning for "unboxing" which triggered interesting answers/comments - consider reading on it at [MSDN:Boxing and Unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

Comment: If you use dynamic instead of var, it should work

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do with the unboxed object? If you're trying to call a method, then you should casting to an Interface.

Comment: Related to that question: If you replace the assignment in your example by `var variable = new {value="Some text"};` and assign it to `obj` you're boxing an anonymous type. How to convert that back? **N.B.** Linqpad shows the type as `<>f__AnonymousType0\`1[System.String]`.

Answer (score 25):

If you don't know the type *at compile time*, then you can't unbox because you have **nowhere to put it** - all you can do is store it in an `object`, which is: boxed.

The same also applies to reference-types like `string`: you can't cast it to the right type if you don't know the type at compile time: you have *nowhere to put it*.

You *can* special-case a few types, for example:

```
if(obj is int) {
    int i = (int)obj;
    ...
} ...
```

Another trick that is *sometimes* (not often) helpful is to switch into *generics*; then instead of talking in terms of `object` you are talking in terms of `T`. This has... limited use though. The easiest way to do that is via *dynamic*, for example:

```
dynamic obj = ...
Foo(obj);
...
Foo<T>(T val) { ... code with T ... }
```

you can also add special cases to that appreach:

```
Foo(string val) { ... code with string ...}
Foo(int val) { ... code with int ...}
```

However, frankly I suggest it may be better to look hard at what you are trying to do.

Comment: +1. One will need to construct generic type at runtime obviously.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov why? frankly I don't see much utility in what the OP is trying to do here...

Comment: +1. Thanks Marc, seeing all these `Convert.ChangeType` answers made me wonder: "How can ChangeType return an unboxed value in an `object`?"

Comment: Neither do I... But if one wants something like `List<ValueTypeKnownAtRuntime>` and add elements to it than such List will need to be constructed based on type of elements... But maybe I misunderstood what you meant about "talking in terms of `T`"...

Comment: I believe you can unbox to unknown type please check the work around I made in my answer.

Comment: Just one tiny note - in OPs question he stated `How to unbox...`, but when you use genetics no boxing occur in the first place. Anyway - great answer

Comment: @IlyaIvanov I was illustrating starting with an `object` and then unboxing *via* generics; and boxing can still happen in generics, depending on what you are doing - for example, an `object` method (such as `ToString()` or `GetType()`) will cause boxing of a generic if the method isn't overridden by the value-type (of course, for `GetType()` it ***cannot*** be overridden). constrained-call (the hybrid that sits between static-call and virtual-call) can only do so much.

Comment: @MarcGravell totally agree, I first wrote, that no boxing occur in simple cases or by default, i.e. passing `int` to `Func<T>(T v)`. Sure you can box any value type in millions of different ways with or without generics

Answer (score 10):

Now lets suppose, that real boxing occur:

```
int v = 5;

object o = v; //boxed 

Type type = o.GetType(); //will return typeof(int)

int convertedBack = (int)Convert.ChangeType(o, type);

Console.WriteLine (convertedBack); //prints 5
```

Remark, if you substitute:

```
object convertedBack = Convert.ChangeType(o, type);

Console.WriteLine (convertedBack); //it still prints 5
Console.WriteLine (o); //it even print 5 here
```

The reason is that underlying object is still `int`. I've just used this example to show you, that boxing is irrelevant here. You need to rely on some abstraction in your operations and if you want to cast to `int` dynamically, what reference type do you wan to use.

Comment: OK but you've used casting to int here. What do i need is smth like `var convertedback = (type)Convert.ChangeType(o, type);`

Comment: @PaulKyrejto syntax issues aside: in what *possible* way would that help you? What could you now do with `convertedback` that you couldn't do when it was `object` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Next Q will be _"how to find all the things I can do with a thing that I don't know the type of?"_...

Comment: @MarcGravell There are certainly refactoring reasons for doing so. Instead of having a bunch of if statements or a switch, you could just do overloaded methods which is a much cleaner way to code.

Answer (score 5):

In such cases I'm going to use the strategy pattern by using a `Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>`:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var something = new Something();

        something.ComputeValue(13);
        something.ComputeValue(DateTime.Now);
        something.ComputeValue(DayOfWeek.Monday);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

internal class Something
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> _Strategies;

    static Something()
    {
        // Prepare all available strategies.
        _Strategies = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();
        _Strategies.Add(typeof(int), ComputeInteger);
        _Strategies.Add(typeof(DateTime), ComputeDateTime);
    }

    public void ComputeValue(object value)
    {
        Action<object> action;

        // Check if we have a matching strategy.
        if (!_Strategies.TryGetValue(value.GetType(), out action))
        {
            // If not, log error, throw exception, whatever.
            action = LogUnknownType;
        }

        // Perform the matching strategy on the given value.
        action(value);
    }

    private static void ComputeDateTime(object source)
    {
        // We get an object, but we are sure that it will always be an DateTime.
        var value = (DateTime)source;
        Console.WriteLine("We've got an date time: " + value);
    }

    private static void ComputeInteger(object source)
    {
        // We get an object, but we are sure that it will always be an int.
        var value = (int)source;
        Console.WriteLine("We've got an integer: " + value);
    }

    private static void LogUnknownType(object source)
    {
        // What should we do with the drunken sailor?
        var unknownType = source.GetType();
        Console.WriteLine("Don't know how to handle " + unknownType.FullName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of exactly why you would do this:

```
class MyClass
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public decimal Val {get;set;}
}
int i = 0;
var myClassImp = new MyClass();
foreach (var val in new [object]{"10", "My name", "100.21"} // Could be read from some data source, such as an excel spreadsheet
{
   var prop = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties().ElementAt(i++);
   // !!!!!! THROWS EXCEPTION  !!!!!!!
   prop.SetValue(myClassImp, System.Convert.ChangeType(val, prop.PropertyType), null);
}
```

The reason for this is because the value is a boxed object... at runtime you do not know the type, so you would have to unbox to the prop.PropertyType

Answer (score 1):

A pragmatic solution; try and use a TypeConverter directly, and if that fails, convert to string and back again:-

```
private static T GetValueOfType<T>(this ManagementBaseObject MBO, String FieldName) {
    T lResult;

    try {
        Object lObj = MBO[FieldName];

        var lSrcType = lObj.GetType();
        var lDestType = typeof(T);

        if (lDestType.IsValueType && lDestType.IsAssignableFrom(lSrcType)) {
            lResult = (T)lObj;
            return lResult;
        }

        var lDestTC = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
        if (lDestTC.CanConvertFrom(lSrcType)) {
            lResult = (T)lDestTC.ConvertFrom(lObj);
        } else {
            var lSrcTC = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(lSrcType);
            String lTmp = lSrcTC.ConvertToInvariantString(lObj);
            lResult = (T)lDestTC.ConvertFromInvariantString(lTmp);
        }
    } catch {
        lResult = default(T);
    }
    return lResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use expressions:

var y = DynamicCast(obj, desiredType);

```
static object DynamicCast(object source, Type type)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "input");

    var cast = Expression.TypeAs(Expression.Convert(parameter, type), typeof(object));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(cast, parameter);

    var func = lambda.Compile();

    return func(source);
}
```

Comment: Does not work. The line `var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(cast, parameter)` errors with `Expression of type 'System.Nullable1[System.Int32]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'`

Comment: Or to be more accurate. Doesn't work for non-nullable types such as int

Comment: Fixed by adding an extra conversion

Comment: It still does not work. What is returned by the lambda is still an object wrapping an int. You can see in the debugger. http://i.imgur.com/d0Ba0Al.png

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetType(object data)
{
    Type type = data.GetType();
    return Convert.ChangeType(data, type).GetType().Name;
}
```

Hi,this method receives object data and returns string type name of object.
Hope this is what you need.

Answer (score -1):

you can try using the dynamic runtime

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_UnboxingAtRuntime()
    {
        object boxed = "Hello";

        //this line is commented out as it does not compile
        // OverloadedMethod(boxed);

        var result = CallCorrectMethod(boxed);
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("string"));

        boxed = 1;
        result = CallCorrectMethod(boxed);
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("int"));
    }

    public string CallCorrectMethod(dynamic t)
    {
        return OverloadedMethod(t);
    }

    public string OverloadedMethod(string s)
    {
        return "string";
    }

    public string OverloadedMethod(int s)
    {
        return "int";
    }
```

Comment: There is no boxing in your sample to start with... And also no traces of unboxing either - not sure what exactly you suggest here...

Comment: What are YOU talking about? The cast of `string` to `object` is the textbook definition of boxing ([see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)), and once in the generic method it has been unboxed as T is equal to System.String, if this had just called `GetTypeName(str)` it would output "System.Object"

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment is now a little wrong as I changed the sample to make it clearer so there is no longer a generic method.

Comment: There is no boxing for `string` as it is reference type (unlike `int` which is value type as shown in linked article). I'm not exactly sure where did you find mentioning of string in relation to boxing in the article ...