# Output an array with multiple return types c#

Tags: c#, arrays, return-type

My error messages say "cannot convert type double to type int[]" and same with `string` and `int` (at the end, `arraySalsa`) I understand why, but I am unsure of how to fix so the array so far takes them all in. Can you help?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] heat = new string[] { "Mild", "Medium", "Hot", "Super Hot", "Scorching" };
        double[] price = new double[4];
        int[] numSold = new int[4];

        int counter;
        {
            for (counter = 0; counter != heat.Length; counter++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What do you wish to charge for " + heat[counter] + " ?");
                price[counter] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("How many jars of " + heat[counter] + " did you sell last year?");
                numSold[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }//end forloop

        } 

        for (int count = 0; count < heat.Length; count++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You sold " + numSold[count] + " of " + heat[count] + " at $" + price[count] + " each.");
        }//end forloop

        Array[,,] arraySalsa;
        arraySalsa = new Array[heat, price, numSold];
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this...just don't.  You should be using classes with collections `List<T>`, not arrays spliced into multidimensional arrays.  There are powerful managed collections available to you and first class objects in the form of classes.  Learn to love them :).

Comment: `Array[,,]` is a three dimensional array of `Array`, it doesn't make any sense. The only way to store objects of completely different types is to store them in `object[]`, which is a 1D array of `object`.

Comment: You should try making a c# class to contain your heat, price, and numSold. You can use an array (or, as per my preference) a List to iterate through that class. You can also have an array of objects (object being the type), but I recommend a class very strongly.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, you should be using a class, not a multidimensional array.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var measurements = new Measurements();
        measurements.Heat = new string[] 
            { "Mild", "Medium", "Hot", "Super Hot", "Scorching" }.ToList(); 
        measurements.Price = new List<double>(4);
        measurements.NumSold = new List<int>(4);

        int counter;
        {
            for (counter = 0; counter != measurements.Heat.Count; counter++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What do you wish to charge for " + 
                    measurements.Heat[counter] + " ?");
                measurements.Price[counter] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("How many jars of " + measurements.Heat[counter] + 
                    " did you sell last year?");
                measurements.NumSold[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        } 

        for (int count = 0; count < measurements.Heat.Count; count++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You sold " + measurements.NumSold[count] + " of " + 
                measurements.Heat[count] + " at $" + measurements.Price[count] 
                + " each.");
        }

        // your arraySalsa is now just your measurements instance
    }
}

public class Measurements
{
    public List<string> Heat { get; set; }
    public List<double> Price { get; set; }
    public List<int> NumSold { get; set; }
}
```

There are number of benefits to using lists over arrays in C#, even when doing simple indexing.  Since they are dynamically resized for you, you do not have to worry about increasing your upper bounds.  In addition, there are powerful `LINQ` methods at your disposal to help you manipulate your collections more easily.  When possible (and unless you have extreme performance considerations) you should always lean towards lists.

Alternatively, you could create a Measurement class that contains each of the three properties and create a collection of that class which would clean up all of the indexing operations.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var measurements = new List<Measurement>();
        var heat = new string[] 
            { "Mild", "Medium", "Hot", "Super Hot", "Scorching" }.ToList(); 

        int counter;
        {
            for (counter = 0; counter != heat.Count; counter++)
            {
                var measurement = new Measurement() { Heat = heat[counter]};
                Console.WriteLine("What do you wish to charge for " +
                    measurement.Heat + " ?");
                measurement.Price = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("How many jars of " + measurement.Heat + 
                    " did you sell last year?");
                measurement.NumSold = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                measurements.Add(measurement);
            }
        }

        measurements.ForEach(x =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You sold " + x.NumSold + " of "
                + x.Heat + " at $" + x.Price + " each.");
        });
    }
}

public class Measurement
{
    public string Heat { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int NumSold { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store different types in an array (or List or whatever) and they dont have a common base class then you need to store them as boxed objects.

```
var salsa = new object[20];
salsa[0] = 1;
salsa[1] = 42.42;
salsa[3] = "hot";
```

to read them you need to do

```
var s1 = salsa[1];
if (s1 is int)
  Console.WriteLine((int)s1);
if(s1 is double)
  COnsole.WriteLine((double)s1);
etc...
```

see [How to unbox from object to type it contains, not knowing that type at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565196/how-to-unbox-from-object-to-type-it-contains-not-knowing-that-type-at-compile-t)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an array of `object`s:

```
object[] arraySalsa;
arraySalsa = new object[] {(object)heat, (object)price, (object)numSold};
```

If you want, you can leave out the typecasting operator, `(object)`, and the compiler will infer that it's supposed to typecast:

```
object[] arraySalsa;
arraySalsa = new object[] {heat, price, numSold};
```

However, using an `object[]` can be bad practice, because given only the type `object[]`, you have no knowledge of what's in it, and the compiler won't stop you from accidentally putting the wrong type of thing in it. Therefore, it may be a better idea to use a `Tuple`:

```
Tuple<string[], double[], int[]> tupleSalsa;
tupleSalsa = new Tuple<string[], double[], int[]>(heat, price, numSold);
```

For convenience, you can use `Tuple.Create` in place of `new Tuple<string[], double[], int[]>`, so that you don't have to write the type out a second time:

```
Tuple<string[], double[], int[]> tupleSalsa;
tupleSalsa = Tuple.Create(heat, price, numSold);
```

Answer (score 0):

the hole idea of creating an array of multiple types is wrong (break data coherence). If u use object as suggested, you will have a lot of boxing/unboxing to do latter. I would suggest to create a class product with 3 attributes : Temperature, price, quantity & work with a List of Products ...