# Exception when casting double to float?

Tags: c#, casting

I'm having a weird issue.

I'm receiving "Cannot cast from source type to destination type"-exception when trying to cast from double to float, but I can't understand why and why this (see below) works any different.

```
//this throws exception
void doSomething1(object val)
{
   if(val is double || val is float)
   {
      doSomethingElse((float)val);
   }
}

//this works
void doSomething2(object val)
{
   if(val is double || val is float)
   {
      double tmpDouble = (double)val;
      float tmpFloat = (float)tmpDouble;
      doSomethingElse(tmpFloat);
   }
}

void doSomethingElse(float val)
{
//do something
}
```

I've checked the `Type` of `val` and it is `System.Double`, so what is wrong here?

EDIT:
Someone flagged this has duplicate (which it *kinda* is), but the exception I received is not the same as the one received in the "duplicate"-post and thus I could not locate this exact problem (especially since I was stupid enough to not understand it was an (un)boxing issue).

Comment: Unboxing doesn't consider conversions, you can only unbox a double to `double` or `double?`.

Comment: So, `(float)(double)val` for val having type `System.Double`.

Comment: Your second code will fail if the value is a `float`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55(v=vs.110).aspx and then cast to float

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565196/how-to-unbox-from-object-to-type-it-contains-not-knowing-that-type-at-compile-t).

Comment: Ahh thank you all for your quick answers! And thanks for the related question @user202729 . It helped me understand my issue more clearly!

Comment: Be careful -- dupe questions tend to be downvoted ("this question does not show any research effort").

Comment: As a C# dev but non-expert in these boxing issues, I also agree see that the marked duplicate is *related* but not really/clearly pointing to the solution to the problem. I voted to reopen, so someone can post a clear solution. However, there seems to be some debate in the review queue (alternating "Reopen"s and "Leave closed"s) :/